# Exception Handling, C#

Tags: c#, exception

I came across this situation however I don't know how do I handle this exception when the user enters a number outside of the index of the string or any other datatype. In that condition I want the program to display the exception and go back to the first if statement. The code must be as basic as possible as I have just started learning programming. I know the use of 'Try Catch' (or so I think) but I can't determine how to use it here.

```
choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
if (arr[choice] != 'X' && arr[choice] != 'O')
{
  if (player % 2 == 0)
  { 
    arr[choice] = 'O';
    player++;
  }
  else
  {
    arr[choice] = 'X';
    player++;
  }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Sorry the row {0} is already marked with {1}", choice,arr[choice]);
Console.WriteLine("\n");
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using exceptions for flow control.  What you should do is check if the input is correct, and if it's not, prompt the user to input again.  You know users can enter undesirable input, so you should handle that case instead of `try catch`

Comment: How do i stop the program from terminating if the use enter any other datatype?@Zer0

Comment: I would need to see more code.   Minimal code that encapsulates the problem.  I have no idea how you're getting your input, for example.  It looks like you're writing Tic-Tac-Toe.  But probably the important part is where you get the user input really.

Comment: choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); just before the If statement @Zer0

Comment: If you don't want to use exception, use `int.TryParse` instead of `int.Parse` and compare `choice` against the allowed range `0 ... arr.Length - 1` before accessing an array element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
int choice;
bool isValidChoice = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out choice) && choice >= 0 && choice < arr.Length;
if (isValidChoice && arr[choice] != 'X' && arr[choice] != 'O') {
  if (player % 2 == 0) {
    arr[choice] = 'O';
    player++;
  } else {
    arr[choice] = 'X';
    player++;
  }
} else if (!isValidChoice) {
  Console.WriteLine("Sorry you have not entered a valid in-range integer");
} else {
  Console.WriteLine("Sorry the row {0} is already marked with {1}", choice, arr[choice]);
  Console.WriteLine("\n");
}
```

#### Some explanations:

1. `int.TryParse`, is effectively the equivalent of

```
int choice;
bool isValid = false;
try {
    choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    isValid = true;
} catch {}
```

2. `&&` will only be evaluated only when the previous statement is correct. So in
   `choice >= 0 && choice < arr.Length` the `choice < arr.Length` will only be checked if the `choice >= 0` is correct
3. If you want to retry as long as the input is invalid. Try using the `while(!isValidChoice)` loop. I will not tell you how, as I think it will be a good learning experience.

Comment: This can still throw if choice is < 0 or >= arr.Length

Comment: True, I fixed that too.

Comment: Looks good, but would be more useful to show how to prompt the user for input if it's incorrect.  That's up to OP, but since this question is for beginner's it would be really useful to see that, imho.

Comment: I added some explanations and an excerisice too, to help him with learning.

Comment: Good added info, however `int.TryParse` does not throw exceptions (even internally).  I dislike that comparison.  Here's the [code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/int32.cs,152).

Comment: That;s why I said the equivalent and not the same: https://wikidiff.com/equivalent/same

Comment: Exceptions unwind the stack, which is expensive, among a host of other things.  But I digress.